# Expressing dependencies between values of a record in types

Tags: haskell, dependent-type

Suppose we're trying to represent an AST node of a C-like language. First, let's define the notion of the node kind, for simplicity:

```
data CursorKind = KIntegerLiteral | KStringLiteral | KFunction | KStruct | KTypedef
```

Next, let's add a type to represent the values of the literals in a type-safe manner:

```
data LiteralValue k where
  IntegerValue :: Int -> LiteralValue 'KIntegerLiteral
  StringValue :: String -> LiteralValue 'KStringLiteral
  NotALiteral :: LiteralValue '???
```

That's the first question: is there a way to define the `NotALiteral` clause so that it implies any `k` except `KIntegerLiteral` and `KStringLiteral`? If not, what's the best way to express this kind of fallback-ish clause to avoid repetition?

Anyway, now, given the above, let's construct a very simple representation of a node in the AST:

```
data Cursor = Cursor
  { kind :: CursorKind
  , value :: LiteralValue ???
  , children :: [Cursor]
  }
```

That's the second question. What I'd ideally like to have is the type of `value` to depend on the `kind`. In a language with full dependent types like Idris it'd be blatantly simple. But how do we do this in modern Haskell with all the singletons and `TypeInType` it has to offer?

---

**EDIT** Inspired by @chi's answer, my solution to the first question is to use a type family in the following way, as in reality there is a ton of cursor kinds and enumerating all of them just seems wrong:

```
type family NotALiteral (k :: CursorKind) :: Bool where
  NotALiteral 'KIntegerLiteral = 'False
  NotALiteral 'KStringLiteral = 'False
  NotALiteral a = 'True

data LiteralValue k where
  IntegerValue :: Int -> LiteralValue 'KIntegerLiteral
  StringValue :: String -> LiteralValue 'KStringLiteral
  NotALiteral :: NotALiteral k ~ 'True => LiteralValue k
```

The problem is now in the implementation of a function that produces a matching `LiteralValue` given a cursor kind `k`. Ideally, we'd like to have something with the following signature (yes, I'm using `singletons`):

```
getLiteralValue :: Sing k -> FFICursor -> FFIMonad (LiteralValue k)
```

The implementation for the cases where `k` is indeed a literal is straightforward:

```
getLiteralValue SKIntegerLiteral ffi = IntegerValue <$> ffiGetInt ffi
getLiteralValue SKStringLiteral ffi = StringValue <$> ffiGetStr ffi
```

but if we now try to write something like

```
getLiteralValue _ _ = pure NotALiteral
```

it won't typecheck, as ghc is not able to derive that `NotALiteral k ~ 'True` holds. One solution is to continue matching on the singleton, but it would effectively require enumerating all of the kinds which, again, is something I'd like to avoid due to their numbers. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use the `first-class-families` package to make a custom TypeError with a custom check for the constraints.

Starting off with the language extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE
    GADTs,
    StandaloneDeriving,
    ConstraintKinds,
    DataKinds,
    TypeFamilies,
    TypeInType,
    TypeOperators,
    ExplicitNamespaces,
    FlexibleInstances,
    UndecidableInstances 
    #-}
```

Next, the imports

```
import Data.Kind (Constraint)
import Data.Type.Equality (type (==))
import Data.Type.Bool (If, type (||))
import GHC.TypeLits (TypeError, ErrorMessage(..))

-- package: first-class-families
import Fcf (Eval, Exp, Pure)
```

Next, we need to define a data type to defer the type error, so it's not evaluated unless necessary. Also define a type instance for the `Eval`

```
data TypeError' :: ErrorMessage -> Exp a
type instance Eval (TypeError' m) = TypeError m
```

Now the types we are gonna use

```
data CursorKind = KIntegerLiteral | KStringLiteral | KFunction | KStruct | KTypedef 

-- Singletons for pattern matching on NotALiteral, can be generated with the singletons package
data SCursorKind (k :: CursorKind) where
  SKIntegerLiteral :: SCursorKind 'KIntegerLiteral
  SKStringLiteral :: SCursorKind 'KStringLiteral
  SKFunction :: SCursorKind 'KFunction
  SKStruct :: SCursorKind 'KStruct 
  SKTypedef :: SCursorKind 'KTypedef

deriving instance Show (SCursorKind k)

data LiteralValue (k :: CursorKind) where
  IntegerValue :: Int -> LiteralValue 'KIntegerLiteral
  StringValue :: String -> LiteralValue 'KStringLiteral
  NotALiteral :: TestLit k => SCursorKind k -> LiteralValue k

deriving instance Show (LiteralValue k)
```

I've added Show instances for simple testing. Now you might be wondering where `TestLit k` comes from, here's it's definition, using `Eval` and `Pure` from `first-class-families` and `ConstraintKinds`:

```
type TestLit k = Eval (
  If (k == 'KIntegerLiteral || k == 'KStringLiteral)
    (TypeError' ('Text "Wrong CursorKind, shouldn't be KIntegerLiteral or KStringLiteral, but got: " :<>: 'ShowType k)) 
    -- ^could probably give a better TypeError
    (Pure EmptyConstrant)
  )

-- because (Pure (() :: Constraint)) has way too many parentheses
type EmptyConstrant = (() :: Constraint)
```

At this point we're at the same point as chi got us, that is we get a type error when we try to compile the expression `NotALiteral SKIntegerLiteral` (also for string literals).
You could also have used a simple type family for the constraint (with the custom TypeError) instead of using the `first-class-families` package.

Now for the second question:

To achieve what you want you can use a type class. I'm going to simplify the question a bit. Say we want a function `SCursorKind k -> LiteralValue k`, and we want to specialize it for the literals and have it default for others without having to specify all of them. We'll define a type class:

```
class LitVal k where
  getLiteralValue :: SCursorKind k -> LiteralValue k
```

We'll only be exporting the function `getLiteralValue`, and not the type class itself, since we want to provide all the instances. We'll need FlexibleInstances and UndecidableInstances for those, and the OVERLAPPING and OVERLAPPABLE pragmas.

```
instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} LitVal 'KIntegerLiteral where
  getLiteralValue _ = IntegerValue 4

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} LitVal 'KStringLiteral where
  getLiteralValue _ = StringValue "4"

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} TestLit k => LitVal k where
  getLiteralValue sk = NotALiteral sk
```

You can make the type class more complex (with extra arguments) if you wish. You can also drop the `SCursorKind k` from the constructor if you so wish (but it provides a nicer `Show` instance in my opinion)

[Here's a runnable example online, using the defintions from Fcf inlined, and Data.Type.Equality since those seem to cause trouble on that site](https://tio.run/##jVdLb9tGEL7rVwycwqIASaechCqA7MiuEdcJKie9NViRI2khcpdZLi0JdX@7OzNcSqQeaXOQubvz/OaZlSrWmKZvb38P3sHj5On@6@R@2gH6dz/5@Fz05XPmlUlUag1@RKdftFlW97fWFN4pbfwnbZJA/FF51Tg@73K8U5lONTZuHgz/Hs6fc3TKWxdIpts81bH2TyrDIldxzXqX4lbPU2IvyKT99VeTYKwT1XwBeXk3@KfT0VlunRfDhmwZRAfD@6K@1xkMoEnGl8Ppj1Kl2u8g8nSEaDzu9YAIVZ6jcgV4C7EqCwTvbEm6QRvw2g5dSX@t7YOxkDtLLxmUBaEG97/dQmpjlaa7YedE3421KUQPiz5U@l5fe/Xn9XWlmj9AF2BNuiOZmMDCOvArhAQX2mhSbwpYOJud8aPWSFbIw6P2BUT8NXXOuj7In9@xKNQSo@Gw1@swLoT/mi5GsNCu8IM4VUUxWISQNoC7ixcQTV9U2uf49eFL6QKwJiXTyP2zdhJbHwidGOGB8DRdDypJQNV6YYUO@0AZKPwBUOV1XGEjluwu@TzqaLPQW3gP47F48wqTFh8H0WZ56REYf1QGMPAOO03CSMFoBOseCYJoHr7pV6K2YSMp4xZkN70vYQ5jOsjn9XV1Oad3@aAf6D67khm@88V3vrhTaYHBRMlSuxBDBym@YAq4zR1FRnCjV9xS7Oc7hkQ7oJcy9UIejKYIiB4Fgw@S4kHydC8GkEJVctG1/eQIQoTsmggRJ1WnkxC2ElM5s1h5rnh1KLvALWRbggq2opeCjg4ameYIY02GNJqBRLjZLSqNe6auWNTI0J@b0ODL2JD9GTIx6XPpQBSsCc1K1W3pCusE@zF8ejAel@ioSKg1pRyUmXeUxY2Lu9LEnMnhsYw9f7EmchhEzYw4UvSS7aQ7V564DVD@xisuCWJ@sn4ShPa5AGCOsETDDZFivNF@JYlfHCSFyqisnjXMjtYM0uGit0/M2bE/RNfk7B69C0vb4ROO1rMw7AE5oa1farmM1TmBfC80NYonROGBEjLMokPkZyu7gahJvu6FxA1WfqOUx5/AFECoyIiGzpxmLe5zUAkSe67qeIbxGLFG6JnvGQtPR1jD@EPL6/WJrPVl/9t0VQ@XmqhbaKM0pHJoHNmNjLOqTls0krYEj5HreD84eQrFK4zXmAxZw43lPGVxzQ4/RxJdV/vxvlDVbcPpULochwUHiVpj96QOXyE8tMDsybhvVn3Ufcath6s/nSWMDmDSsFnZMk140FClHcsnb9uS@zAvPSytH8EVjH79MIIu4ywta01TWRQTAH/FLFXmEy0iO1jqF4KWVHDFH/Cs7JQGOc1yvwuYGM8eVMGaY7VWVFRRJB34gB3pXKkCNoqHl6VWYnbUERwaClCBAdW2bIL2VIzowq3KclpdOMoFUngT@FFSRCh6fV4wyAORJ1NfhuXKWromtzYYkiLRC0ob5JxgWRl9KQk/K9h3@pPdTfLx3Oom7fnb9I/HyZcvD0/3QlefJzePU8JYLTOCgJyuliCya4VpLvtVMLDKVueQGkpdICx4Z8uQANUSRXOVlxchZx9pXKBfWVpf6U55gbmwGdLy29pODG72coedCh7KGKo6ys@6nSzRt6rxqJmdLet9NfNG3oSBdtlaw0lVXFLIm0Wrp73/vwravf9n8pvN7@r91QUFEjjW0Gpy/4lYwW2h2SaLteRtFQpPM3TNi9K@zgz9j6GTUX5L9/4MUa86jSGxJD533Lp@aUk8jC0WfIHkCG8i3Og0rRcvUtDYVEAvgCTajCsBk4baY@9mzbl4mehk3lwmbU@Yztvbvw)

Answer (score 2):

If you only care about preventing construction, you can use

```
data LiteralValue k where
  ...
  NotALiteral :: NonLiteral k => LiteralValue k

class NonLiteral k
instance NonLiteral 'KFunction
...
```

Note that, in this approach, the value of `k` gets erased before runtime, so we won't be able to pattern match on that.
If knowing `k` is important, then we can use a singleton

```
data SCursorKind c where
    SKIntegerLiteral :: SCursorKind 'KIntegerLiteral
    SKStringLiteral  :: ScursorKind 'KStringLiteral
    ...

data LiteralValue k where
  ...
  NotALiteral :: NonLiteral k => SCursorKind k -> LiteralValue k
```

so that we have something to pattern match on.

(The singleton type can also be autogenerated using the `singletons` library, I think.)

For the second question, use an existential and a singleton:

```
data Cursor where
   Cursor ::
      { kind :: SCursorKind k
      , value :: LiteralValue k
      , children :: [Cursor]
      } -> Cursor
```

This changes the type of the field `kind` a bit. If that's a problem, it is trivial to write a `fromSCursorKind :: SCursorKind k -> CursorKind` function to recover the original type.

Comment: Many thanks! I have slightly modified the solution for the first problem (see the edit), as I really don't want to enumerate all of the cursor kinds. But I still have a problem with the second question (again, see the update). Do you have any ideas about that?